# python ssh(paramiko) fail to connect to remote machine without password?

Tags: python, ssh, sftp

I want to connect to my remote machine with python module [`paramsiko`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_sftp.py). First, I try with password, it is ok, like this:

```
import paramiko
import socket
import os

paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo_sftp.log')
username = 'xxxxx'
hostname = 'dev81'
Port = 22
password = "xxxxx"
t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, Port))
t.connect(None, username, password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
# dirlist on remote host
dirlist = sftp.listdir('.')
print("Dirlist: %s" % dirlist)
```

then I want to remove password, use key, according to demo in [`demo_sftp`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_sftp.py) like this:

```
import paramiko
import socket
import os

paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo_sftp.log')
username = 'xxxxx'
hostname = 'dev81'
Port = 22
password = None
host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
hostkeytype = host_keys[hostname].keys()[0]
hostkey = host_keys[hostname][hostkeytype]
print('Using host key of type %s' % hostkeytype)
t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, Port))
t.connect(hostkey, username, password, gss_host=socket.getfqdn(hostname),
            gss_auth=True, gss_kex=True)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
# dirlist on remote host
dirlist = sftp.listdir('.')
print("Dirlist: %s" % dirlist)
```

This **fail** with **Exception** `paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType: ('Bad authentication type', [u'publickey', u'password']) (allowed_types=[u'publickey', u'password'])`

And I can login with command `ssh xxxxx@dev81` without password

Comment: from what I understand, you should either use public key authentication OR user/password authentication. I'd suggest you just do this `t.connect(hostkey, gss_host=socket.getfqdn(hostname),
            gss_auth=True, gss_kex=True)`. Notice I took out the user and positional arguments there.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean no, it doesn't work. And also I do not think I should remove username, according to [API](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/transport.html?highlight=connect#paramiko.transport.Transport.connect), password is default None, it doesn't matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362051/how-to-connect-to-remote-server-with-paramiko-without-a-password

Comment: If you are trying to implement a sftp client, you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362171/5781248 (use of `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file`); *.ssh/known_hosts* is not used in case of a ssh / sftp client.

Answer (score 2):

If you Have **passphrase** for the Key pair

**It throws this error**

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.BadAuthenticationType: ('Bad authentication type', [u'publickey', u'password']) (allowed_types=[u'publickey', u'password'])
```

**To Resolve this**

```
ssh.connect('<your ip>', port=22, username='<username>',password='<passphrase for the RSA key>', key_filename='<full path of the private key>')
```

Comment: What is this passphrase for the RSA key